# Create automatic tick labels for a tkinter scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, scale

I want to create a scale with tick labels that are automatically chosen so they fit on to the scale without interfering with each other.

Here is an example code for crating one that resizes with the window:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

scale = Scale(from_=1, to=1000, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scale.pack(fill=X)

window.mainloop()
```

When creating a plot with `matplotlib`, this happens by default and even gets updated when changing the size of the plot window.

Is there a way to accomplish the same for a `tkinter` scale widget? The result should look something like this:

[image: scale example image]

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, there is an option called `tickinterval`.

From a doc:

> Normally, no “ticks” are displayed along the scale. To display periodic scale values, set this option to a number, and ticks will be displayed on multiples of that value. For example, if from_=0.0, to=1.0, and tickinterval=0.25, labels will be displayed along the scale at values 0.0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, and 1.00. These labels appear below the scale if horizontal, to its left if vertical. Default is 0, which suppresses display of ticks.

So:

```py
from tkinter import * # Better to use `import tkinter as tk`

root = Tk()

var  = StringVar()
Label(root,textvariable=var).pack()

Scale(root,from_=1, to=25, orient=HORIZONTAL, tickinterval=1, showvalue=0, variable=var, length=1000).pack(fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:
[image: ss]

For more info, read: [21. The Scale widget](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/scale.html)

---

However what you are asking is for an automatic calculation algorithm with which `tkinter` would resize and fit in the `length` to the scale, sadly it is not available AFAIK and this is the closest method I can think of.

Comment: @LukasFun I don't think there is any option that does this dynamically. So basically you need some algorithm that does this calculation, were you asking us to make that algorithm? Then I think it is off topic for this site

Comment: @LukasFun I don't think there is an option like that, but you can wait a day or so for a professional opinion :)